# C++ windows pause timer

Tags: c++, c, windows, timer

I'm using `SetTimer` to create a timer in my application with an interval of 50ms, this timer is going to be used to draw an object, and move it around.

Now I don't want the object to move when the window is out of focus, but I still need it to be painted.
And having it paint every 50ms, seems unnecessary. And performance is extremely important in this project.

So I need a way to pause the timer, but still draw the object, but preferably only when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get WM_ACTIVATE, decide whether to call KillTimer or SetTimer.

Comment: But if the timer is not running, the objects won't be painted. I could put them in `WM_PAINT`, and call `WM_PAINT` from the timer, but calling `WM_PAINT` that often seems like a performance hit?

Comment: Well, make up your mind.  If you get WM_ACTIVATE to tell you that you are no longer active, what exactly is supposed to happen next?  +1.

Comment: I'd like the objects to still be painted, but only when necessary, if the window is out of focus. But if it is in focus, paint them like normal every 50ms.

Comment: When Windows knows that your window needs to be painted, Windows sends you WM_PAINT.  So in your WM_PAINT handler you need to paint your objects.  Your original posting didn't say that you weren't doing that.  Now you know that you have to do that.

Comment: But then I would have to call WM_PAINT, every 50ms, and repaint the entire window. When I only need to paint 1 or 2 objects. So I was doing the painting in the timer. Problem is, when it's out of focus and i've killed the timer, the objects aren't being painted.

Comment: You can do both - paint in the timer when you're focused, but always respond to WM_PAINT and paint everything when asked to. You have to do that anyway to be a well-behaved application.

Comment: You should do all painting in WM_PAINT and have your timer just do an InvalidateRect on the portion of the window containing the object.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note aside to you initial problem.

I would not rely on Windows Timer with such low resolution. It's a low priority message and if you have lots of heavy duty things going on in you program, the timer might be invoked at higher intervals that you expect.